# Do I need to do something to turn on WiFi on my new Pi 3?

Tags: wifi

I just got a new Pi 3 and downloaded and installed the latest Raspbian Noobs.

Pi is up and running and connects to Internet through direct wired connection to router.

The icon for Bluetooth displays on the toolbar grayed out and there is no WiFi icon.

As my username says I am an older novice with no experience beyond using commercial applications on Windows machines. No unix/linux experience at all.  That's what I got the Pi for.

Is there something I need to do to turn on WiFi?  All the videos I've watched seem to indicate it should be automatic with the Pi 3.

Comment: If "there is no WiFi icon" you have either changed a config file, or have a faulty install.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **WiFi and the GUI** set up by following the Foundation Guidelines
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md

If you are using **WiFi from the Command Line** set up `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` by following https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md
This is the only way to set up a network which does not broadcast `SSID`.